# Load data to android list view with record id and pass the exact record id onListItemClick

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

Im getting my data from a web service and loads to a list view. Which is working fine. but When I click on a particular list item I need to pass the id of that record (Id should is coming from the database) to another activity. Here is the code where I populate the array

```
public String[] getNames(String response){
    String[] friends = null;
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
        String values = json.getString("friends");
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(values);
        friends = new String[jsonArray.length()];
        //Bundle b = new Bundle();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            friends[i] =  jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("fname")+ " " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("lname") ;
            friends[i+1] = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
            //i++;  
            //friends[i]= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return friends;
}
```

This is the code Im trying to get the name and the ids

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    // Get the item that was clicked
    Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    String name = o.toString();
    Object x = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position+1);
    String userid= x.toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, "You selected: " + name +"The Id: "+userid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
}
```

This is my xml file for the list view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#ffffff"
>
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/icon"
android:padding="2dip"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/man"
/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/txtName"
android:layout_width="210px"
android:layout_height="60px"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:textSize="12sp" 
    android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:background="#ffffff"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is how I populate the list view

```
public void setTheList(String response){
        String friends[] = getNames(response);
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        if(adapter==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, lv, false);
            lv.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
        }

        adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this, friends);
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

This is my Adapter. I got it from [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

```
package virtualpathum.web;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] names;

    public MyArrayAdapter(Activity context, String[] names) {
        super(context, R.layout.friend, names);
        this.context = context;
        this.names = names;
    }

    // static to save the reference to the outer class and to avoid access to
    // any members of the containing class
    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView textView;
        public ImageButton ibConfirm;
        public ImageButton ibNotNow;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // ViewHolder will buffer the assess to the individual fields of the row
        // layout

        ViewHolder holder;
        // Recycle existing view if passed as parameter
        // This will save memory and time on Android
        // This only works if the base layout for all classes are the same
        View rowView = convertView;
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friend, null, true);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            //holder.ibConfirm = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ibNotNow);
            //holder.ibNotNow= (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ibNotNow);
            rowView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        holder.textView.setText(names[position]);
        // Change the icon for Windows and iPhone
        String s = names[position];
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.man);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Really appreciate if you have idea about this
Thanks
Pathum

Comment: post the code of how you are populating the view.

Comment: @YashwanthKumar I updated the code. please check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you have no problem to get the id back. However, you could supply a Tag to any View (so you can pass the id as Tag inside the LinearLayout). Then if you have your id you could start your new Activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), YOUR_ACTIVITY_YOU_WANNA_START.class);
intent.putExtra("ID", userid);
startActivity(0, intent);
```

in the recieving Activity (in this case YOUR_ACTIVITY_YOU_WANNA_START.class) you call maybe in onCreate()

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String userId = intent.getExtra("ID" , "DEFAULT");
```

Comment: How can I set the value to Tag? I tried to set the textView.setTag(userid) when fetching the data from the db. but it gives me nullpointer exception. `friendName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) { 
friends[i] =  jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("fname")+ " " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("lname") ;    friendName.setTag(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));

   }`

Comment: you can't get NullPointerException in `friendName.setTag(..)` I thin that either getJSONObject returns null or `getString(id)`returns null. You can try it with `friendName.setTag(null)`to confirm it cannot be `setTag`

Answer (score 1):

Instead getnames returning String[]create a class representing a person together with an id and return ArrayList

```
class Person {
   String name;
   int id;
   public Person(int id, String name){
   //Implement
   }
   //Implement getters and setters      
}

//Consider renaming to getPersons
ArrayList<Person> person = getNames();

getNames(String inputString)
{
   ...
   ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList...
   persons.add(new Person("Brother",2)
   persons.add(new Person("Jonas",1)
   return persons;
}

ArrayAdapter<Person> arrayadapter = new YourArrayAdapter<Person>();
arrayadapter.addAll(getNames(inputString);


In you arrayadapter you override the getItemId
@Overide
getItemId(int position)
{
   return getItem(position).getItemId();
}
```

(I assume you are using an ArrayAdapter or something similar)

And then in your arrayadaper implement getId and getItem accordingly

Comment: I can set the values to Person Object inside the getNames(). but how could I retrieve the id back in the item on click? please explain little bit.

Comment: Please mark answer that solve your problem/answer your question as "accepted" (green checkbox to the left) so other know what solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

ok, here is what you do, add a new member to your holder class, lets assume your id data type is string. then add

```
public String mId;
```

to the holder. and populate it with the relating id of the view before returning from the getView.

```
holder.mId = Id_which_you_need;
```

in onItemClickListener, use this to get the Tag.

```
holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
```

and to get the Id, as we assumed it's a string.

```
id = holder.mId;
```

id is what you need.This is all you need, there are other ways too, since you are using Tags, I thought this would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for all the given support. I used the approach which @Richard provided with @rafael-t's Tag concept. Thanks @yashwanth-kumar for the explanation. Following are the modifications did to my original codes

```
public ArrayList<Object> getNames(String response){
        ArrayList<Object>  arrList = null;
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
            String values = json.getString("friends");
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(values);
            arrList = new ArrayList<Object>();
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {  
                arrList.add(new User(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"),jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("fname"),jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("lname"),jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("email")));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return arrList;
    }
```

This is my getNames Method I added all the values to User Object. Thanks to @Richard .

Here is my Custom Adapter for this change

```
package virtualpathum.web;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<Object>> {
    private final Activity context;
    private final ArrayList names;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public MyArrayAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList names) {
        super(context, R.layout.friend, names);
        this.context = context;
        this.names = names;
    }

    // static to save the reference to the outer class and to avoid access to
    // any members of the containing class
    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView textView;
        public ImageButton ibConfirm;
        public ImageButton ibNotNow;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // ViewHolder will buffer the assess to the individual fields of the row
        // layout

        ViewHolder holder;
        // Recycle existing view if passed as parameter
        // This will save memory and time on Android
        // This only works if the base layout for all classes are the same
        View rowView = convertView;
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friend, null, true);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            //holder.ibConfirm = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ibNotNow);
            //holder.ibNotNow= (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ibNotNow);
            rowView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }
        String [] frndNames = new String[names.size()];
        int count = 0;
        for (@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Iterator iterator = names.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            User user = (User) iterator.next();
            frndNames[count] = user.getFirstname()+" "+user.getLastname();
            count++;
        }
        String [] frndIds = new String[names.size()];
        int idCount = 0;
        for (@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Iterator iterator = names.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            User user = (User) iterator.next();
            frndIds[idCount] = user.getUserid();
            idCount++;
        }
        holder.textView.setText(frndNames[position]);
        holder.textView.setTag(frndIds[position]);
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.man);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

This is the on click Listener

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        // Get the item that was clicked
        String userid = (String) v.findViewById(R.id.txtName).getTag();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Selected user ID = "+userid , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
```

I still feel this can be further optimize for better performance but for now it's more than enough for me. Thank you guys again.

Answer (score 0):

In the long click event you have a position parameter. Wherever you store your data, you can get it with this parameter. For further help, you should probably add some information about the type of adapter you use.

Comment: I think the position parameter gives the item position in the list view. I want to set my own id to the list item and get it back in the click event